# Sorting warnings by accumulated count and date within a specified date range in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django project where I need to sort warnings based on the accumulated warning count (warning_count) and the date (date) within a specified date range (start_date and end_date). Here is my code:

```
    class LatestWarningListView(generics.ListAPIView):
        serializer_class = LatestWarningSerializer
        pagination_class = ListPagination
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
        filterset_fields = ['student__school_year', 'student__attending', 'type']
        search_fields = ["student__name"]
        ordering_fields = ['date', 'warning_count']
        permission_classes = [IsTeacher]

        def get_queryset(self):
            self.pagination_class.page_size = 10

            start_date_str = self.request.query_params.get('start_date', None)
            end_date_str = self.request.query_params.get('end_date', None)

            start_date = parse_date(start_date_str) if start_date_str else None
            end_date = parse_date(end_date_str) if end_date_str else None

            latest_warning = Warning.objects.filter(student=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')

            if start_date:
                latest_warning = latest_warning.filter(date__gte=start_date)

            if end_date:
                latest_warning = latest_warning.filter(date__lte=end_date)

            students = Student.objects.annotate(latest_warning_id=Subquery(latest_warning.values('id')[:1]))
            warning_ids = [student.latest_warning_id for student in students if student.latest_warning_id is not None]
            warnings = Warning.objects.filter(id__in=warning_ids)

            return warnings


class LatestWarningSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    warning_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id', read_only=True)
    student_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='student.id', read_only=True)
    warning_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Warning
        fields = ['student_id', 'student_name', 'warning_id', 'type', 'date', 'content', 'warning_count']

    def get_student_name(self, obj):
        return obj.student.name

    def get_warning_count(self, obj):
        start_date_str = self.context['request'].query_params.get('start_date', None)
        end_date_str = self.context['request'].query_params.get('end_date', None)

        start_date = parse_date(start_date_str) if start_date_str else None
        end_date = parse_date(end_date_str) if end_date_str else None

        warnings = Warning.objects.filter(type='경고', student=obj.student)

        if start_date:
            warnings = warnings.filter(date__gte=start_date)

        if end_date:
            warnings = warnings.filter(date__lte=end_date)

        return warnings.count()
```

However, the sorting is not working correctly. I want to sort the warnings based on the accumulated warning count (warning_count) and the date (date) within the specified date range. How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: Well where do you sort in the "final" queryset? You only return `Warning.objects.filter(id__in=...)`, so no sorting at all.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes i wanna ordering by warning_count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide any models. I just went ahead and implemented my own solution. In any case, what you are looking for is inside `.filter_queryset` method at `views.py`.

models.py

```
class Student(AbstractUser):
    school_year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    attending = models.BooleanField(null=True)


class Warning(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="warnings"
    )
    date = models.DateField()
    content = models.TextField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializers.py

```py
class WarningSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Warning
        exclude = ["student"]


class StudentWarningSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serilaizer for students warings"""

    student_id = serializers.IntegerField(source="student", read_only=True)
    student_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    warning_count = serializers.IntegerField()
    latest_warning = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    warnings_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_student_name(self, obj):
        return Student.objects.get(pk=obj["student"]).get_full_name()

    def get_latest_warning(self, obj):
        latest = Student.objects.get(pk=obj["student"]).warnings.latest("date")
        return WarningSerializer(latest).data

    def get_warnings_list(self, obj):
        student = Student.objects.get(pk=obj["student"])
        if self.context["range"]:
            start_date = self.context["range"]["start_date"]
            end_date = self.context["range"]["end_date"]
            return student.warnings.filter(
                date__range=(start_date, end_date)
            ).values_list("id", flat=True)

        return student.warnings.values_list("id", flat=True)
```

views.py

```
class StudentWarningListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """Endpoint for listing students warnings."""

    queryset = Warning.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentWarningSerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        """
        Filter queryset if 'start_date' and 'end_date' params are provided
        aggregate data
        """
        start_date = self.request.query_params.get("start_date", None)
        end_date = self.request.query_params.get("end_date", None)

        if start_date and end_date:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))

        queryset = (
            queryset.order_by("date")
            .values("student")
            .annotate(warning_count=Count("id"))
            .order_by("-warning_count")
        )

        return super().filter_queryset(queryset)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        start_date = self.request.query_params.get("start_date", None)
        end_date = self.request.query_params.get("end_date", None)
        dates_range = (
            {"start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date}
            if start_date and end_date
            else None
        )

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(
                page, many=True, context={"range": dates_range}
            )
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            queryset, many=True, context={"range": dates_range}
        )
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Output sample (with pagination)

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/warnings/?end_date=2023-06-30&limit=2&offset=2&start_date=2023-06-01",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "student_id": 4,
            "student_name": "Test Student",
            "warning_count": 3,
            "latest_warning": {
                "id": 5,
                "date": "2023-06-05",
                "content": "Vandalization of school property.",
                "type": "2"
            },
            "warnings_list": [
                5,
                6,
                7
            ]
        },
        {
            "student_id": 2,
            "student_name": "Student One",
            "warning_count": 2,
            "latest_warning": {
                "id": 1,
                "date": "2023-06-05",
                "content": "Smoking in the toilets.",
                "type": "1"
            },
            "warnings_list": [
                1,
                3
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, the endpoint accepts both URL's, with and without filters, e.g:

```
http://localhost:8000/warnings/
```

and

```
http://localhost:8000/warnings/?start_date=2023-06-01&end_date=2023-06-30
```

There are only two things out of the ordinary, one is the [`aggregation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-order-by) and the second one is passing [`extra context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) to the serializer.